# Serialize an external object

Tags: java, serialization, bloomberg

I am programming towards the Bloomberg Desktop Java API where I subscribe to and recieve market data in `Message` objects, containing different fields and corresponding values of different types, through the API. I want to 'record' a sequence of messages so that I can conduct testing of my code that processes these objects by replaying a known sequence of messages. Ideally, I would like to subscribe to a number of messages during a day and put them into an `ArrayList` (or similar) and then serialize the list of objects. However, the `Message` object does NOT implement the `Serializable` interface so this does not appear to work the way I want it to.

Is it possible, or is there any workaround, to serialize external objects that do not implement `Serializable`. Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256308/serialization-of-java-object-created-from-external-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way that I know of is [xStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org).  Here is a [FAQ](http://xstream.codehaus.org/faq.html#Serialization) from the xStream website specifically about this

Comment: Thanks. I actually went down the route of trying to wrap the Message objects according to some of the other suggestions as that seemed to be the 'proper' solution but it turns out these `Message` objects are around half a Megabyte each with infinite fields so I gave up. I am now using XStream which works remarkably well. My only problem now (not connected to XStream) is that the exported files quickly becomes serveral Gigabytes in size so I will need to roll files and invest in more disk space :-).

Comment: Did you ever attempt to serialize the `Event` objects themselves? I tried but get ClassCastExceptions.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the `Message` object and implement [Externalizable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html) interface, whereby you can write the serialization/deserialization logic in `readExternal/writeExternal` methods.